# How can I have a constant variable common to all classes in a package?

Tags: java

I want a constant variable to be common to all classes in a package.  Is there a way I can do this without making an interface just with the one definition in it, and making every class implement that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Java, all constants have to reside in a type (class or interface). But you don't have to implement an interface to use a constant declared inside.

You can try by putting something like this in your package:

```
interface Constants {

    static final String CONSTANT = "CONTANT";

}
```

and then, using it like this:

```
String myVar = Constants.CONSTANT;
```

This way, you still have your interface, but no classes implement it.

Comment: Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final.

Comment: Effective Java, Item 19 "Use interfaces only to define types" explicitly recommends against this usage of interfaces. Use classes for constants, or enums, if possible

Comment: @seanizer, can you please send me that pdf my mail id is there with my profile.

Comment: @olj sorry, haven't got a pdf edition. but you can sometimes find one online via google.You should get the book, though. it's well worth the money.

Answer (score 5):

Generally applications have a "Constants" class or interface that holds all constants.

I generally to to group constants into logical classes. For instance if there can be two kinds of employees, regular and contract:

```
class EmployeeType
{
   public static final String REGULAR = "regular";
   public static final String CONTRACT = "contract";
}
```

and use it as `EmployeeType.REGULAR`

If the constants cannot be grouped this way, have a separate class/interface to hold these.

```
class Constants
{
   public static final String APPLICATION_DOMAIN = 'domain';
}
```

You need not extend/implement this class interface to use the values. The constants will generally be declared `public static final`, you can access them *directly*: `Constants.APPLICATION_DOMAIN`

Answer (score 2):

Use a package private class:

```
class Constants{

    public static final int MY_VALUE = 1234;

}
```

This can only be accessed by classes from the same package:

```
int val = Constants.MY_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in various ways:

- One way (as mentioned here) is to create a Global constant interface and have a `public static final` attributes of each constants.`
- Create properties file. By having a properties file, you'll have a Key value pair (separated by a `=` operator) each declared on a newline. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-08/01-qa-0808-property.html) on how to create and use properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like to be a good candidate for an entry in a property file to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an abstract class to serve as the base class for each impls in that package.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a special (static) class with just this variable. Later you can add other constants or whatever you need to that class.